# The Python Tools server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The Python Server Crashes Unexpectedly. Am able to run in debug mode but the Linting is not working. Could anybody help me out please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the following documentation, then edit, and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Derry_Jay_10 Could you paste the log of the `Python Language Server`? You can find it in the OUTPUT panel -> Python Language Server channel.

Comment: You can try this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3977.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this by following the steps to reinstall the Python extension found here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13679#issuecomment-683899458

Copying steps here:

> 1. Uninstall Python extension (if you have pylance uninstall it first).\
> 2. Close all instances of VS Code.\
> 3. Go to, %USERPROFILE%/.vscode/extensions (on windows) or ~/.vscode/extensions on Linux/Mac.\
> 4. Delete any folder with the name starting with ms-python.python*\
> 5. Start VS Code, and install Python extension (also pylance if you uninstalled it in step 1).

Comment: This totally worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, which I resolved based on [this answer](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1118#issuecomment-876280173). What I found was opening the folders individually seemed to work fine, but if I opened the workspace it caused the issues.

Deleting the workspace and creating a new one seemed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is facing this issue in the containers then this did the trick for me:

Run the following the command inside the container:

```
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/
```

Reopen vscode

It removes all the cached data for that particular container.

Answer (score 1):

### Change the language server to Pylance

Go to VSCode Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Python -> Change the "Language Server" setting to "Pylance" (install Pylance extension if needed)

Answer (score 0):

I had turned on "Python: Pylance Lsp Notebooks Enabled" setting. Turning it off did the trick.